# Contour linewidths not changing

Tags: matplotlib, contour, contourf, linewidth

I am using the `clabel` function to draw contour lines on a contour plot. I have the following relevant piece of code, for which I keep getting the error message: The following kwargs were not used by contour: 'linewidth'.

The current output has contours with a large line width that I would like to reduce. Why is this not working? Is there anything that looks wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors

from matplotlib import gridspec#, ticker
X=np.loadtxt("x.txt")
Y=np.loadtxt("y.txt")
Z2=np.loadtxt("z2.txt") 

extent = [X[0], X[-1], Y[0], Y[-1]] 
zmin = min(np.amin(Z2)) 
zmax = max(np.amax(Z2)) 

clev = np.arange(zmin,zmax,0.0005)
cax=ax.contourf(X,Y,Z2,clev)
cax=ax.imshow(Z2, vmin = zmin, vmax = zmax, aspect='auto',
          origin="lower", extent=extent, alpha=0.5)

contours = plt.contour(X, Y, Z2, 2, linewidth=0.001, colors='black')
plt.clabel(contours, inline=True, fontsize=8)
```

Comment: Please use `linewidths`

Comment: @JodyKlymak, easy fix thanks for spotting that!